# How convert a date ("yyyy-mm-dd") into a julian date with a Spark function?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a date:

```
"2009-01-15"
```

How convert in julian date with a Spark function?

Expected result:

```
2454847
```

I use `R` language and try use this [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In spark scala, its easy with java time apis as below-

```scala
  val toJulian =
      udf((str: String) => java.time.LocalDate.parse(str).getLong(java.time.temporal.JulianFields.JULIAN_DAY))
    Seq("2009-01-15").toDF("date")
      .withColumn("julian_date", toJulian($"date"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+-----------+
      * |date      |julian_date|
      * +----------+-----------+
      * |2009-01-15|2454847    |
      * +----------+-----------+
      */
```